# Network of multisites in Wordpress, create new site with all the contents of the main

Tags: multisite, network-admin, multisite-user-management

I started a project in Wordpress months ago, I have completely configured the website, design, content, templates etc ... Now I want to create a network of sites, I have configured it and launched it with this manual https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network, but when I create a new site, the whole site is not duplicated, it's as if I installed Wordpress again, in the new created site.

It is possible that I can create a new site by cloning all the data from the main website?

Comment: WordPress won't copy all your content from your main site to a new site. Each site in a multisite network is separate, and will be essentially blank when you create it. It's likely that there exist plugins to clone sites in a Multisite network, but you'll have to search for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Multisite Clone Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/) plugin.